# What are these clip-like things?

Tags: airline-operations, feature-identification

With me becoming an aviation enthusiast and AirBerlin becoming insolvent, my mom has gone on a hunt for deals on what I can best describe as AirBerlin merch (old uniforms, shirts, skirts, belts and many more).

In one of the packets that arrived recently she found items that neither her nor I knew the purpose of.

They are about 2cm * 2cm, yellow, have some kind of number on them and on most of them was the writing "Air-Berlin SEALED" or "airberlin group SEALED" and an engraved "PULL". It also looks like you can break off and bend a part in the plastic to the back and clip it there.

Below is a picture I took of a few of these:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Galley seal. It works like a cable tie, you can put one end inside a hole on the main body but you can't pull it out without destroying the seal.

The cabin crew will seal the galley carts containing alcohol and other duty-free items before landing and note the seal numbers in their report. This is required by law in a lot of countries.

Comment: That makes sense! Do you have an image of one of these in their designated place by any chance?

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Admittedly, this is not from AirBerlin, but in [this picture](https://hilcoindprodstorage.blob.core.windows.net/proj-3749/3749_381111_500.jpg?1555947932) you can see a seal on a cart. Different airlines use different seals, naturally.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant galley seals in general, not only AirBerlin; thanks for the picture!

Comment: Do you know any way to find more information about the laws that require this? Keywords to search with or case numbers etc

Comment: @cat seals like this aren't limited to the drinks cart on airlines - basically, any inventoried/counted stuff left in a rack/tray/etc. could use it.  Hospital I worked at we used them all the time on crash carts to ensure everything was there and proper, to close/seal/latch large tubs of equipment to designate them as being "clean and ready for patient use", etc.  They basically provide an easy accounting/control method that has something almost like an audit trail on it...

Comment: Electric utilities in the US us something similar. Since it can't be opened without destroying the seal, but destroying the seal is easy, it's not meant as security, simply as a means of tamper identification.

Comment: Oh indeed! A search for "crash car seal" bring up the ones that look like the bottom one in my picture. Great hint!

Comment: Of course, all one has to do to make the tampering undetectable is to carry a seal with them to reseal whatever they're tampering with after they're done tampering with it.

Comment: The seals are numbered and sometimes this will help identify if the seal has been broken. Eg when someone seals it, the seal number is usually recorded and simlarly at the other end when the cart is opened. If any discrepancy is noted the seal numbers will be compared.

Comment: Not fool proof but it works for the most part.  It's usually required to be sealed for different conditions. Eg some countries require all liquor cart to be sealed before landing. Duty free carts are also sealed when the flight is completed to prevent any items being stolen. Its not perfect but there are several safeguards in place. For instance seals are color coded to departments.. the flight kitchen will use one colour, cabin crew and security will use others.

Comment: Also the seals are numbered and it is possible to trace the seals as they should be recorded when issued to a person. Having said that it all depends on discpline as I've seen them lying around in the galleys.